# Group MySQL result only if next row has the same key

Tags: ios, mysql, sql

I'm trying to mimic the way Apple's iOS is sorting the call history on the Phone App.

The way they're sorting the calls is as the following:

```
(original list)
—————————————————————
John - (Incoming)       - 10.30 am
John - (Missing)        - 10.00 am
John - (Outgoing) (3)   - 09.00 am
John - (Outgoing)       - Wednesday

(An incoming call is done)
—————————————————————
John - (Incoming) (2)   - 10.30 am <-- this row gets grouped (2)
John - (Missing)        - 10.00 am
John - (Outgoing) (3)   - 09.00 am
John - (Outgoing)       - Wednesday

(A missed call came)
—————————————————————
John - (Missing)        - 10.35 am <-- this row gets added (but not grouped with (*))
John - (Incoming) (2)   - 10.30 am
John - (Missing)        - 10.00 am --> (*)
John - (Outgoing) (3)   - 09.00 am
John - (Outgoing)       - Wednesday
```

Basically, the thing this App is doing is the following:

It gets all the calls from the database, if two or more calls are equals in type (missing,incoming or outgoing), and also are the next row, they get grouped into one row and a numeric indicator shows the grouped amount, otherwise, the row is simply added to the table view without any strange action.

The thing I'm trying to do is that grouping by type when next row is same type as previous row. I know how to do it with code, **but** I want to know if there is any way to do it via **ONLY SQL**.

Comment: I'm removing the SQLite tag, because the title is explicitly about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you share a fiddle sql which you have already created the DDL statements and all the support could go in finding the best query however assuming you have a table and 3 columns here is what I can compose.

```
select name, type_of_call, count(type_of_call), last(call_time) from call_history
group by name, type_of_call;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do this using variables:

```
select calltype, count(*) as numcalls, max(calltime)
from (select ch.*,
             (@rn := if(@t = type_of_call, @rn,
                        if(@t := type_of_call, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                       )
             ) as grp
      from CallHistory ch cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @t := '') vars
      order by calltime
     ) ch
group by grp, calltype;
```

This is adding a "ranking" variable to the call types.  The variable only increments when the call type changes.  The output query groups the values together to provide the "summary" information.